# How to get Firefox to show XML document trees in a monospace font

Tags: firefox, fonts, xml

I would like Firefox to display XML document trees in a monospace font, instead of using the default proportional serif font.

For a single document I can do this from the menu View->Page Style->Monospace, but it falls back to the default if I reload the document or fetch a new one.

Is there a way to permanently change the font used for rendering XML document trees in Firefox without affecting the way non-XML documents are rendered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: The following solution will also affect the `View Source` browser.

1. Edit the file `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\res\viewsource.css`
2. Add the line `font-family: monospace;` to the `*|*:root` block.
3. Restart Firefox.

Example (truncated file):

```
...
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml); /* set default namespace to HTML */

*|*:root {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
}
...
```

Comment: Not a very clean solution, but if it's the only way to accomplish what I want, I'll use it. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Ubuntu Lucid, and there the file is located at /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.6/res/viewsource.css.

Comment: @Lars: Agreed, not a clean solution, but I couldn't think of another way.

Comment: This solution does not work with Firefox 11 (the file does not exist). Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Firefox plugin that does exactly that: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xml-monospace/

Comment: True, but this feels quite spammy for a plugin that was released 4 days ago and has 6 users. How are you affiliated with this? Are you really David?